# why 1 and a retuned 1 are the same object

Tags: object, dart

I'm confused,,who can explan it to me ,my code:

```
int fun1() {
  return 1;
}

int fun2(int x) {
  return x + x;
}

void main() {
  print(identical(1, fun1()));
  print(identical(2, fun2(1)));
}
```

---

### result:
true
true

my question:
why const 1 and fun1() are the same object
const 2 and fun2() are the same object ?? thanks

Comment: All of the primitive types are immutable, and therefore are created as identical objects if they are reasonably equal.  This includes symbols: `#foo` is the same object as `#foo` everywhere.

Comment: thank you for your answer,it makes me a little clear,,,,but the dart doesnt differ the object created in or out of a function when it is aprimitive type?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you executed fun1() which returned 1 and now you comparing 1 and 1 which is obviously true and true.

Comment: `identical` doesn't compare just for equality, but for being exactly the same object.

Comment: what about fun2?  does it means that if there is a object of the same value  ,then the function will return a reference to that object without building a one?